# How to zip two lists of tuples by row?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, list, dataframe

I have two lists like so:

```
list1 = [{'id':'1','id2':'2'},{'id':'2','id2':'3'}]
list2 = [{'fname':'a','lname':'b'},{'fname':'c','lname':'d'}]
```

How do I combine the lists into one set of tuples for a pandas dataframe?

like so:

```
final_list = [{'id':'1','id2':'2','fname':'a','lname':'b'},{'id':'2','id2':'3','fname':'c','lname':'d'}]
```

the dataframe should look like this:

```
id     id2      fname     lname
1       2         a          b
2       3         c          d
```

tried this so far:

```
final_list = list(zip(list1,list2))

df = pd.DataFrame(final_list)

df:

0                          1
[{nested_data}]          [{nested_data}]
```

Comment: What have you tried so far ? :)

Comment: @IMCoins made edit with what I tried

Comment: I think the terminology in the question could be improved for future users. Tuples are a built-in Python data type that isn't present in this problem (do you mean dictionaries? or are you referring to the paired data structure?)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can just use `pd.DataFrame.join`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(list1).join(pd.DataFrame(list2))

print(df)

  id id2 fname lname
0  1   2     a     b
1  2   3     c     d
```

Comment: exactly what I am looking for!

Answer (score 5):

You should do [pd.concat](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.concat.html#pandas.concat).

As per the documentation, it seems that @jpp answer is better in terms of performance. I'd be more inclined to believe a benchmark, but honestly, I trust the [pandas documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/merging.html#database-style-dataframe-joining-merging).

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(list1)
df2 = pd.DataFrame(list2)

result_df = pd.concat([df, df2], axis=1)

#result_df
#  id id2 fname lname
#0  1   2     a     b
#1  2   3     c     d
```

Comment: why use concat vs join as @jpp suggested?

Comment: @RustyShackleford, `concat` is extendible for greater than 2 dataframes. If you only have 2 dataframes, `concat` & `join` are more or less equivalent (`join` marginally faster, but probably not going to be your bottleneck).

Comment: See my edit, but yes, what he said +  i'd say if you look for performance, join is better.

Answer (score 5):

A "pure" Python answer (ie no Pandas):

```
[{**x[0], **x[1]} for x in zip(list1, list2)]

> [{'id': '1', 'id2': '2', 'fname': 'a', 'lname': 'b'},
    {'id': '2', 'id2': '3', 'fname': 'c', 'lname': 'd'}]
```

Edited by Scott Boston

```
pd.DataFrame([{**x[0], **x[1]} for x in zip(list1, list2)])
```

Output:

```
  fname id id2 lname
0     a  1   2     b
1     c  2   3     d
```

Comment: Wrap that in pd.DataFrame, `pd.DataFrame([{**x[0], **x[1]} for x in zip(list1, list2)])` and you'll get OP expected output.